# Is there a way I can install pillow on my windows machine?

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

**I tried installing the pillow library but I got this message**

(venv) C:\Users\Timo\PycharmProjects\jumia>pip install pillow
Collecting pillow
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3e/02/b09732ca4b14405ff159c470a612979acfc6e8645dc32f83ea0129709f7a/Pillow-7.2.0.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: pillow
Running setup.py install for pillow ... error
Complete output from command C:\Users\Timo\PycharmProjects\jumia\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\Timo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gr4big0c\pillow\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Timo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-yl39rrsa\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\Timo\PycharmProjects\jumia\venv\include\site\python3.8\pillow:
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\BdfFontFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\BlpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\BmpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\ContainerIO.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\CurImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\DcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\DdsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\EpsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\ExifTags.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\features.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\FliImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\FontFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\FpxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\FtexImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\GbrImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\GdImageFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\GifImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\GimpGradientFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\GimpPaletteFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\IcoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\Image.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageChops.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageCms.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageColor.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageDraw.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageDraw2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageEnhance.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageFilter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageFont.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageGrab.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageMath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageMode.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageMorph.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageOps.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImagePalette.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImagePath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageQt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageSequence.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageShow.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageStat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageTk.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageTransform.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageWin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImtImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\IptcImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\JpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\JpegPresets.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\MicImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\MpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\MpoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\MspImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\PaletteFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\PalmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\PcdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\PcfFontFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\PcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\PdfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\PdfParser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\PixarImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\PngImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\PpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\PsdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\PSDraw.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\PyAccess.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\SgiImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\SunImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\TarIO.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\TgaImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\TiffTags.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\WalImageFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\WebPImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\WmfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\XbmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\XpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL\XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL_binary.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL_tkinter_finder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
copying src\PIL_*main*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\PIL
running egg_info
writing src\Pillow.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to src\Pillow.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to src\Pillow.egg-info\top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching '*.c'
warning: no files found matching '*.h'
warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
no previously-included directories found matching '.ci'
writing manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext

```
The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

Please see the install instructions at:
   https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Timo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gr4big0c\pillow\setup.py", line 864, in <module>
    setup(
  File "C:\Users\Timo\PycharmProjects\jumia\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Timo\PycharmProjects\jumia\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 340, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "C:\Users\Timo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gr4big0c\pillow\setup.py", line 694, in build_extensions
    raise RequiredDependencyException(f)
__main__.RequiredDependencyException: zlib

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Timo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gr4big0c\pillow\setup.py", line 918, in <module>
    raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
__main__.RequiredDependencyException:

The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

Please see the install instructions at:
   https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html



----------------------------------------
```

Command "C:\Users\Timo\PycharmProjects\jumia\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\Timo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gr4big0c\pillow\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Timo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-yl39rrsa\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\Timo\PycharmProjects\jumia\venv\include\site\python3.8\pillow" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Timo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gr4big0c\pillow\

Comment: If you add details about how you installed it and what you have tried, it will be easier to help.

Answer (score 2):

Try installing it like this:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
python3 -m pip install --upgrade Pillow
```

Comment: MeL is correct installation instructions with "upgrade pip" before installing Pillow:  https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html

Answer (score 2):

```
For install pillow:
                       pip install pillow
For Upgrade pillow:
                       python3 -m pip install --upgrade Pillow
For upgrade pip:
                       python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 0):

I found something on Reddit [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/dz8hiz/i_am_stuck_the_headers_or_library_files_could_not/)

Quazaka 3 points · 7 months ago

I solved the problem. in order to install Pillow a newer version of pip is needed. The installation of python 3.8 only include pip version 19.0.x where pip version 19.3.x is needed. In order to upgrade pip run the following command in the venv (terminal in PyCharm)

```
python -m pip install -U --force-reinstall pip
```